# Drupal 7 | Update content via API endpoint?

Tags: api, drupal, endpoint

Maybe anybody knows some good modules to create an API endpoint, so that users can create/update content via API calls with POST variables?

To extend the question:

Basically I need to write a custom module with a stable authentication endpoint:

```
// Use some module, to provide authentication to this endpoint

function example_menu() {  
    $items = array();  
    $items['api/v2/endpoint'] = array(    
        'page callback' => 'example_accept',    
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),    
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,  
    );  

    return $items; 
}

function example_accept() {
    // Identify if user has permission to edit some nodes
    // Read $_POST vars
    // Use post data to update nodes, that belongs to the user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe check out this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/services

It is quite complex so you should take some time to check the documentation, for example the services handbook: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/services